# Uploading a file to a directory

Tags: php, file

I am quite new to PHP and I am trying to upload a file to a newly created directory on my ftp server, e.g. the new directory name is newDir located in the root directory, I am not too sure how the paths work in PHP,  how do I code this in PHP its however not uploading the file, is my path I am directing it to wrong?

```
<?php
if($_FILES){
//checking if a file is selected
if($_FILES['file']['name'] != ""){
//check if file is of type plain text file if not exit
 if(isset($_FILES) && $_FILES['file']['type'] != 'text/plain') {
 echo "<span>  This is not an accepted file format, upload a .txt   
 document</span>";

exit();
 }
 echo "<center><span id='Content'> Contents of ".$_FILES['file']['name']."  
 File</span></center>";
//Getting and storing the temporary file name of the uploaded file
 $fileName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
 //echo "File has been uploaded and saved as" . "upload/" . $_FILES['file'] 
 ['name'];
 //open file or display an error message if file cant open
 $file=fopen($fileName,"r") or exit("Sorry unable to open the selected 
 file");
//reading the contents of the .txt document line by line
while(!feof($file)){ 
echo fgets($file) . " "; 
}
// reading a .txt file character by character
while(!feof($file)){ 
echo fgetc($file); 
}
fclose($file);
}
//check if user selects a file to upload
else
  {
if(isset($_FILES) && $_FILES['file']['type'] == '')
echo "<span> Please choose a file by clicking on the 'Browse' or 'Choose     
file' buttons. </span>";
}
}
//if the user clicks on the upload
//save the file to the new created directory on the server
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
//upload file to the server
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "upload/" . $_FILES['file']
['name']);
//create a variable message to hold the file name of the uploaded file
$msg = "New file ".$_FILES['file']['name']." has been uploaded to the server
 <br />";}'
```

Comment: one line of code just doesn't make the cut. Start with the manuals on uploading and for error checking.

Comment: what's `NewDir` ? should it be a var? or a string?

Comment: the path you need to specify here is relative to web-root. and you need to pass it as string here: `move_upload_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "NewDir/" .$_FILES['file']['name'];`

Comment: believe it or not, php has a manual!  http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: @PedroLobito Ironically enough, they do. I told them to start with the manuals, but I was just too lazy to give them the link; *or was I?*. Hm... oh well, it's Sunday, I'm allowed to be lazy *lol*

Comment: @Jeff thank you, I am not sure what you mean,can you please clarify. I have updated the code. it works fine on my localhost when I create a folder, but when I create a folder on the FTP site it doesn't work the same.

Comment: Thank you PedroLobito and Fred

Comment: then maybe the newly created folder is not correct chmoded for writing!

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sunday... talking about manuals...I'm on lynda learning laravel ;)

Comment: @PedroLobito Not a bad way to spend a Sunday.

Comment: @Fred-ii- not at all, I dig laravel!

Answer (score 0):

This is the line moving your file from a temporary cache folder to the location where you want the file to be stored at:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "upload/" . $_FILES['file']['name']);
```

Right now, you are moving the file to a directory called `upload` in the same directory this script is currently located at.  This is what the folder structure would look like:

```
-Current folder
    -this_script.php
    -upload
        -my_new_file.txt
```

If you want to move your script to a folder called `newDir` under the root web server folder, you'll want to use something like this:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/newDir/' . $_FILES['file']['name']);
```

Comment: Hi Lloyd, thank you so much, that helps a lot, when I upload I however do not think the file gets uploaded to the NewDir directory -                       Root->NewDir (within this folder)

Comment: @phenom5001 Can you check to see if the httpd / apache user has access to write to the root web folder?

Comment: I am probably going to sound super daft, but where would I find that information, I am using one of these free hosting sites (www.freewebhostingarea.com/)

Comment: @phenom5001 The httpd / apache user is the system user that runs the web server.  PHP runs under the web server, which means this user has to have write permission on the folder that you want to add files to.  If you are using one of the free hosting sites, you won't be able to log into your server through the command line and check whether the httpd / apache user has write access.  If this user can't write to your web site's folder, you won't be able to accept uploads onto your server.  I would suggest opening up an AWS account and using an EC2 instance to host your site (1st year is free).